# Creating a class for an already working program in Python

Tags: python

I have recently started working in Python and got an assignment where we are supposed to take a existing code without a class in it and rewrite it using a class and self.example variables.

I decided to use the following code found online:

```
 1. """A command line version of Minesweeper""" import random import re
import time from string import ascii_lowercase


def setupgrid(gridsize, start, numberofmines):
    emptygrid = [['0' for i in range(gridsize)] for i in range(gridsize)]

    mines = getmines(emptygrid, start, numberofmines)

    for i, j in mines:
        emptygrid[i][j] = 'X'

    grid = getnumbers(emptygrid)

    return (grid, mines)


def showgrid(grid):
    gridsize = len(grid)

    horizontal = '   ' + (4 * gridsize * '-') + '-'

    # Print top column letters
    toplabel = '     '

    for i in ascii_lowercase[:gridsize]:
        toplabel = toplabel + i + '   '

    print(toplabel + '\n' + horizontal)

    # Print left row numbers
    for idx, i in enumerate(grid):
        row = '{0:2} |'.format(idx + 1)

        for j in i:
            row = row + ' ' + j + ' |'

        print(row + '\n' + horizontal)

    print('')


def getrandomcell(grid):
    gridsize = len(grid)

    a = random.randint(0, gridsize - 1)
    b = random.randint(0, gridsize - 1)

    return (a, b)


def getneighbors(grid, rowno, colno):
    gridsize = len(grid)
    neighbors = []

    for i in range(-1, 2):
        for j in range(-1, 2):
            if i == 0 and j == 0:
                continue
            elif -1 < (rowno + i) < gridsize and -1 < (colno + j) < gridsize:
                neighbors.append((rowno + i, colno + j))

    return neighbors


def getmines(grid, start, numberofmines):
    mines = []
    neighbors = getneighbors(grid, *start)

    for i in range(numberofmines):
        cell = getrandomcell(grid)
        while cell == start or cell in mines or cell in neighbors:
            cell = getrandomcell(grid)
        mines.append(cell)

    return mines


def getnumbers(grid):
    for rowno, row in enumerate(grid):
        for colno, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell != 'X':
                # Gets the values of the neighbors
                values = [grid[r][c] for r, c in getneighbors(grid,
                                                              rowno, colno)]

                # Counts how many are mines
                grid[rowno][colno] = str(values.count('X'))

    return grid


def showcells(grid, currgrid, rowno, colno):
    # Exit function if the cell was already shown
    if currgrid[rowno][colno] != ' ':
        return

    # Show current cell
    currgrid[rowno][colno] = grid[rowno][colno]

    # Get the neighbors if the cell is empty
    if grid[rowno][colno] == '0':
        for r, c in getneighbors(grid, rowno, colno):
            # Repeat function for each neighbor that doesn't have a flag
            if currgrid[r][c] != 'F':
                showcells(grid, currgrid, r, c)


def playagain():
    choice = input('Play again? (y/n): ')

    return choice.lower() == 'y'


def parseinput(inputstring, gridsize, helpmessage):
    cell = ()
    flag = False
    message = "Invalid cell. " + helpmessage

    pattern = r'([a-{}])([0-9]+)(f?)'.format(ascii_lowercase[gridsize - 1])
    validinput = re.match(pattern, inputstring)

    if inputstring == 'help':
        message = helpmessage

    elif validinput:
        rowno = int(validinput.group(2)) - 1
        colno = ascii_lowercase.index(validinput.group(1))
        flag = bool(validinput.group(3))

        if -1 < rowno < gridsize:
            cell = (rowno, colno)
            message = ''

    return {'cell': cell, 'flag': flag, 'message': message}


def playgame():
    gridsize = 9
    numberofmines = 10

    currgrid = [[' ' for i in range(gridsize)] for i in range(gridsize)]

    grid = []
    flags = []
    starttime = 0

    helpmessage = ("Type the column followed by the row (eg. a5). "
                   "To put or remove a flag, add 'f' to the cell (eg. a5f).")

    showgrid(currgrid)
    print(helpmessage + " Type 'help' to show this message again.\n")

    while True:
        minesleft = numberofmines - len(flags)
        prompt = input('Enter the cell ({} mines left): '.format(minesleft))
        result = parseinput(prompt, gridsize, helpmessage + '\n')

        message = result['message']
        cell = result['cell']

        if cell:
            print('\n\n')
            rowno, colno = cell
            currcell = currgrid[rowno][colno]
            flag = result['flag']

            if not grid:
                grid, mines = setupgrid(gridsize, cell, numberofmines)
            if not starttime:
                starttime = time.time()

            if flag:
                # Add a flag if the cell is empty
                if currcell == ' ':
                    currgrid[rowno][colno] = 'F'
                    flags.append(cell)
                # Remove the flag if there is one
                elif currcell == 'F':
                    currgrid[rowno][colno] = ' '
                    flags.remove(cell)
                else:
                    message = 'Cannot put a flag there'

            # If there is a flag there, show a message
            elif cell in flags:
                message = 'There is a flag there'

            elif grid[rowno][colno] == 'X':
                print('Game Over\n')
                showgrid(grid)
                if playagain():
                    playgame()
                return

            elif currcell == ' ':
                showcells(grid, currgrid, rowno, colno)

            else:
                message = "That cell is already shown"

            if set(flags) == set(mines):
                minutes, seconds = divmod(int(time.time() - starttime), 60)
                print(
                    'You Win. '
                    'It took you {} minutes and {} seconds.\n'.format(minutes,
                                                                      seconds))
                showgrid(grid)
                if playagain():
                    playgame()
                return

        showgrid(currgrid)
        print(message)

playgame()
```

This code works just as it's supposed to. This is what i've managed to change it into (I've most likely not understood some basic parts which is why it's not working).

```
 1. import random import re import time from string import
ascii_lowercase

class Minesweeper:


    def __init__(self, numberofbombs, gridsize):
        self.numberofbombs = numberofbombs
        self.gridsize = gridsize

    def setupgrid(self, start):
        emptygrid = [['0' for i in range(self.gridsize)] for i in range(self.gridsize)]

        mines = Minesweeper.getmines(self, emptygrid, start)

        for i, j in mines:
            emptygrid[i][j] = 'X'

        grid = Minesweeper.getnumbers(emptygrid)

        return (grid, mines)


    def showgrid(self, grid):
        self.gridsize = len(grid)

        horizontal = '   ' + (4 * self.gridsize * '-') + '-'

        # Skriver ut bokstäverna för kolumnerna
        toplabel = '     '

        for i in ascii_lowercase[:self.gridsize]:
            toplabel = toplabel + i + '   '

        print(toplabel + '\n' + horizontal)

        # Skriver ut radnummer
        for idx, i in enumerate(grid):
            row = '{0:2} |'.format(idx + 1)

            for j in i:
                row = row + ' ' + j + ' |'

            print(row + '\n' + horizontal)

        print('')


    def getrandomcell(self, grid):
        self.gridsize = len(grid)

        a = random.randint(0, self.gridsize - 1)
        b = random.randint(0, self.gridsize - 1)

        return (a, b)


    def getneighbors(self, grid, rowno, colno):
        self.gridsize = len(grid)
        neighbors = []

        for i in range(-1, 2):
            for j in range(-1, 2):
                if i == 0 and j == 0:
                    continue
                elif -1 < (rowno + i) < self.gridsize and -1 < (colno + j) < self.gridsize:
                    neighbors.append((rowno + i, colno + j))

        return neighbors


    def getmines(grid, start, self):
        mines = []
        neighbors = Minesweeper.getneighbors(grid, *start)

        for i in range(self.numberofmines):
            cell = Minesweeper.getrandomcell(grid)
            while cell == start or cell in mines or cell in neighbors:
                cell = Minesweeper.getrandomcell(grid)
            mines.append(cell)

        return mines


    def getnumbers(grid):
        for rowno, row in enumerate(grid):
            for colno, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell != 'X':
                    # Hämtar värdet av närliggande bomber
                    values = [grid[r][c] for r, c in Minesweeper.getneighbors(grid,
                                                                  rowno, colno)]

                    # Räknar hur många som är minor
                    grid[rowno][colno] = str(values.count('X'))

        return grid


    def showcells(grid, currgrid, rowno, colno):
        # Exit function if the cell was already shown
        if currgrid[rowno][colno] != ' ':
            return

        # Show current cell
        currgrid[rowno][colno] = grid[rowno][colno]

        # Get the neighbors if the cell is empty
        if grid[rowno][colno] == '0':
            for r, c in Minesweeper.getneighbors(grid, rowno, colno):
                # Repeat function for each neighbor that doesn't have a flag
                if currgrid[r][c] != 'F':
                    Minesweeper.showcells(grid, currgrid, r, c)


    def playagain():
        choice = input("Vill du testa igen?? (y/n): ")

        return choice.lower() == 'y'


    def parseinput(self, inputstring, helpmessage):
        cell = ()
        flag = False
        message = "Denna ruta existerar inte. " + helpmessage

        pattern = r'([a-{}])([0-9]+)(f?)'.format(ascii_lowercase[self.gridsize - 1])
        validinput = re.match(pattern, inputstring)

        if inputstring == 'hjälp':
            message = helpmessage

        elif validinput:
            rowno = int(validinput.group(2)) - 1
            colno = ascii_lowercase.index(validinput.group(1))
            flag = bool(validinput.group(3))

            if -1 < rowno < self.gridsize:
                cell = (rowno, colno)
                message = ''

        return {'cell': cell, 'flag': flag, 'message': message}


def playgame():
    gridsize = int(input("Hur står vill du att spelplanen ska vara? Skriv t.ex 9 för 9x9: "))
    numberofmines = int(input("Hur många bomber vill du ha på spelplanen?: "))
    information = Minesweeper(gridsize, numberofmines)

    currgrid = [[' ' for i in range(gridsize)] for i in range(gridsize)]

    grid = []
    flags = []
    starttime = 0

    helpmessage = ("Skriv kolumnen förljd av raden (t.ex a5). "
                       "För att placera eller ta bort en flagga, lägg till 'f' (t.ex a5f).")

    information.showgrid(currgrid)
    print(helpmessage + " Skriv 'hjälp' för att visa detta  meddelande igen\n")

    while True:
        minesleft = numberofmines - len(flags)
        prompt = input('Välj ruta ({} mines left): '.format(minesleft))
        result = information.parseinput(prompt, helpmessage + '\n')

        message = result['message']
        cell = result['cell']


        if cell:
            print('\n\n')
            rowno, colno = cell
            currcell = currgrid[rowno][colno]
            flag = result['flag']

            if not grid:
                grid, mines = information.setupgrid(cell)
            if not starttime:
                starttime = time.time()

            # Kontrolerar placeringen av flaggor
            if flag:
                # Placerar en flagga om platsen är tom
                if currcell == ' ':
                    currgrid[rowno][colno] = 'F'
                    flags.append(cell)
                # Tar bort flaggan om det redan finns en där
                elif currcell == 'F':
                    currgrid[rowno][colno] = ' '
                    flags.remove(cell)
                else:
                    message = 'Du kan inte placera en flagga här'

            # Skapar en utskrift om det redan är en flagga där
            elif cell in flags:
                message = 'Det är en flagga här'

            elif grid[rowno][colno] == 'X':
                print('Du förlorade\n')
                information.showgrid(grid)
                if information.playagain():
                    information.playgame()
                return

            elif currcell == ' ':
                information.showcells(grid, currgrid, rowno, colno)

            else:
                message = "Denna ruta är redan synlig"

            if set(flags) == set(mines):
                minutes, seconds = divmod(int(time.time() - starttime), 60)
                print(
                    'Du vann! '                        'Det tog dig {} minuter och {} sekunder.\n'.format(minutes,
                                                                      seconds))
                information.showgrid(grid)
                if information.playagain():
                    information.playgame()
                return

        information.showgrid(currgrid)
        print(message)

playgame()
```

Basically what I've done is to create the class "Minesweeper" and make "numberofbombs" and "gridsize" into self. arguments.
At first I had the issue that every "example(grid, etc)" didn't work seeing how they were now inside a class. After I changed them to "Minesweeper.example(grid, etc)" the code now starts as it's supposed to.

The error im getting is the following:

1. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
   "C:\Users\Marcus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\minesweeper2.py",
   line 227, in 
       playgame()   File "C:\Users\Marcus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\minesweeper2.py",
   line 180, in playgame
       grid, mines = information.setupgrid(cell)   File "C:\Users\Marcus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\minesweeper2.py",
   line 17, in setupgrid
       mines = Minesweeper.getmines(self, emptygrid, start)   File "C:\Users\Marcus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\minesweeper2.py",
   line 77, in getmines
       neighbors = Minesweeper.getneighbors(grid, *start) TypeError: getneighbors() takes 4 positional arguments but 10 were given

Whenever I put the "Minesweeper." into "getneighbors(grid, *start)" it adds 6 positional arguments and I just can't seem to get around it.

Does anyone know how this can be fixed or if i took the wrong way from the start and what needs to be done in order to fix the code?
Looking forward to everyone's help!

Comment: In most cases you're correctly using `self` to reference things, but for some reason in various places you're calling methods via `Minesweeper.getneighbors()` or whatever instead. Why?

Comment: Following Daniel's comment, whenever you call a class method, you need to use `self.method`, not `Minesweeper.method`

Comment: That was most likely a lack of knowledge from my side, I am a novice at python.
I switched all `Minesweeper` to `self` and can already see the errors going down. The main error about 10 arguments went down to 4 instead. Thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

You give it one argument plus you unpack a list of size 9 for a total of 10

```
def f(*args):
    print('received the following arguments:')
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)

foo = [1, 2, 5, 8]
f('sauce', *foo) # 5 arguments
```

output:

```
received the following arguments:
sauce
1
2
5
8
```